# my rspec example is passing even though I would expect it to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I can't figure out why my 2nd example is passing even though it should be failing

this is my person_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Person do
  it "must have a first name" do
    subject { Person.new(first_name: "", last_name: "Kowalski") }
    subject.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "must have a last name" do
    subject { Person.new(first_name: "Jan") }
    subject.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

this is my person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  def full_name
    return "#{@first_name}  #{@last_name}"
  end
end
```

My rspec output:

```
Person
  must have a last name
  must have a first name

Finished in 0.09501 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 51711
```

What is even worse is that my further examples are failing/passing in a very unexpected way. It seems that somehow my subject is an instance of Person but with neither the first_name nor last_name assigned

Comment: in your model you are not checking for a last name. add "validates :last_name, presence: true" to you model

Comment: Chris, you are correct, this is the point, but prior to adding the line you mention I wanted the test for it to be red (was green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two main issues here. First, if I'm not mistaken, you're supposed to use `subject` in a group scope, but not within an actual spec. Here's an example from the [rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/subject/explicit-subject#subject-block-is-invoked-at-most-once-per-example):

```
describe Array, "with some elements" do
  subject { [1,2,3] }
  it "should have the prescribed elements" do
    subject.should == [1,2,3]
  end
end
```

Note that the `subject` is declared outside of the `it` block. So, I think it's reasonable to see some unexpected behavior here. I haven't dug into the source code here, but I have a feeling that would be educational.

Secondly, your specs can be greatly simplified by following [these guidelines](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/) from David Chelimsky. Your spec can look more like this:

```
describe Person do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:first_name) }
end
```

Shorter, sweeter, and will probably work correctly.

Comment: muffinista, thank you very, very much :) indeed "it" seems to refer to the subject just outside of the "it" block and you can't redefine it inside, (in my case "it" was referring to a subject which was an instance of class Person cause of the "describe Person do" but an instance of that class was being initialized without any of the variables set), I rerun one of the tests (will work on the other ones now) but everything seems to be making sense now, also thx for suggesting the clearer syntax

Comment: also, this: subject block is invoked at most once per example (from the page you linked to), I was trying to redefine my subject and it started doing crazy things again